# How do you maintain state in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I write a POSH script with some discrete functions.

One function is called `Login` which returns an auth token (of string type), another uses the token to call an API. I don't want to call `Login` each time the user calls the API if a `Login` has already been performed and an auth token obtained. The token only lasts for a session - it doesn't need to be persisted to a DB / disk etc.

Where do I maintain the auth token? Is it up to the user to store the token within their POSH session? Is there anyway I can do that for them within my script?

Comment: a global variable maybe? Depends on what type the token is... could you add more info?

Comment: And depends on how your functions are build and what the scenario is. Are we talking about the same session or between sessions?

Comment: See edits. This is a simple scenario - basically how can I save a small amount of state which can be re-used between independent POSH functions during a session.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something as simple as a global variable.

```
$global:MyToken = 'SomeToken'
```

But more flexible would be do something like [remoting sessions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/26/an-introduction-to-powershell-remoting-part-four-sessions-and-implicit-remoting.aspx). The session is not just a string, but a class with whatever properties or methods needed. And since it is a class, other commands can see that it is a session and not just a string. With that you could do things like this:

```
$session1 = New-MySession -Name Jimmy -Password Secret
$session2 = New-MySession -Name Bob -Password 1234
MyAction -Session $session1 
MyOtherAction -Session $session1 
MyOtherAction -Session $session2
MyYetAnotherAction -Session $session1, $session2
Export-Session $session1 C:\temp\somefile.ses
```

Comment: So the emphasis is on the user to create the long lived object in his/her POSH session then supply it as a param to any API calls?

Comment: @jimmy_terra: Yes. The PowerShell way is to require the user to store the object in a variable in their current session.

Comment: Not always, that's good process there but having a default session isn't bad practice. Quest's Active Directory works like the latter. You connect to a DC with a cmdlet and then run the commands you want (at least it did when I used it a while back).